# How can I override certain breadcrumb segments?

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs

Drupal seems to be adding some default breadcrumbs that come from the URL.  How can I disable this feature? I don't see it in configuration but maybe I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Given that the question is not making clear what exactly those _default breadcrumbs_ are, and you want to be selective on which part to remove from the breadcrumbs, this question is too broad. The only possible answer is _change the service used from Drupal to build breadcrumbs_, but this is a too minimal answer.

Comment: The [Easy Breadcrumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb) module adds quite a bunch of configuration to Drupal's core breadcrumbs. Include/exclude certain path or segments etc..

Comment: And then there's also [`hook_system_breadcrumb_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_system_breadcrumb_alter) you can use to override things.

Answer (score 4):

The default breadcrumb builder is defined in the system services file and has the priority 0:

*system.services.yml*

```
  system.breadcrumb.default:
    class: Drupal\system\PathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder
    arguments: ['@router.request_context', '@access_manager', '@router', '@path_processor_manager', '@config.factory',  '@title_resolver', '@current_user', '@path.current']
    tags:
      - { name: breadcrumb_builder, priority: 0 }
```

If you want to turn off the default breadcrumb builder you define one with a higher priority. This is an example for taxonomy terms:

*taxonomy.services.yml*

```
services:
  taxonomy_term.breadcrumb:
    class: Drupal\taxonomy\TermBreadcrumbBuilder
    arguments: ['@entity.manager']
    tags:
      - { name: breadcrumb_builder, priority: 1002 }
```

With the method `applies()` you choose for which routes the breadcrumb builder should be used:

*TermBreadcrumbBuilder::applies()*

```
  public function applies(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    return $route_match->getRouteName() == 'entity.taxonomy_term.canonical'
      && $route_match->getParameter('taxonomy_term') instanceof TermInterface;
  }
```

The breadcrumb manager checks all applies() methods, starting with the highest priority, until it reaches the default breadcrumb builder, which applies for all routes:

*PathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder::applies()*

```
  public function applies(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    return TRUE;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

In D8, breadcrumbs are now blocks. They can be disabled in Block Layout.

Comment: Hi but I dont want to delete all of the breadcrumbs, just the ones that drupal core adds

Comment: That wasn't the question.